# iOS get tableview cell info into button func

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When clicking a button on a tableview cell, I want to return some cell data into the button action function

TableView Code:

```
var cell = self.myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
     var imgtext:AnyObject?

    if (self.SearchController.active)
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text! = self.searchArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageView?.image = decodedimage           

        let Acceptbutton : UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
        Acceptbutton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 60, 60, 24)
        let cellHeight: CGFloat = 44.0
        Acceptbutton.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 1.4, y: cellHeight / 2.0)
        Acceptbutton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        Acceptbutton.addTarget(self, action: "AcceptClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        Acceptbutton.setTitle("Accept", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.addSubview(Acceptbutton)
```

Button Action:

```
 @IBAction func AcceptClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
   //How can I get the cell.textlabel.text here for that specific
   // cell row that AcceptClick was triggered from?
   // I've tried sender.IndexPath but it returns nil
}
```

I'm trying to get my cell data passed into my AcceptClicked func so I can do some manipulation for the specific cell Acceptclick was triggered from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't want `IBAction` in front of the function because it is not link to the Storyboard.

Secondly, you can use this:

```
func AcceptClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let thisButton = sender as! UIButton
    var position: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position) {
        //get your cell here
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
}
```

If just wanted the row:

You can add `AcceptButton.tag = indexPath.row` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and use:

```
func AcceptClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let button = sender as! UIButton
    row = button.tag
}
```

Comment: I changed it up as you want the actual indexPath and not just the row.

Comment: I got it to work using the code above.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Was it because I put "tableView" instead of "myTable?"

Comment: No your code was perfect, I understood it clearly.  The problem was my stupidity afterwards using a ? instead of ! when extracting the cell!.textLabel!.text

Comment: Thanks again for the help, I definitely appreciate it